# how to set control state in aspx

Tags: c#, control-state

I am trying to study control state when i came across an article in code project

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331981/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-Understanding-ControlState-i

But in that example only "Text" value is kept in control state, what if i have to keep both of them?
So i tried this code

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override object SaveControlState()
    {
        object[] state = new object[2]; // save the 2 properties
        state[0] = Text;
        state[1] = Text1;

        return state;
    }

    protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
    {
        object[] state = (object[])savedState;
        Text = (string)state[0];
        Text1 = (string)state[1];
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. Can anyone please help me out ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: dear friend create a property with a view state and save your state in it

Comment: what if viewstate is disabled? correct me if i am wrong , as i have started to study these things now.

Comment: dear by default viewstate is on

Comment: but if your view state is of for your site then you can enable view state for perpetrate control

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54921/Automatic-ViewState-Properties-with-the-ViewState follow this its the method of saving view state in property

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary or List instead of array

```
protected override object SaveControlState()
{
    var state = new List<string>(); // save the 2 properties
    state.Add(Text);
    state.Add(Text1);

    return state;
}

protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
{
    var state = (List<string>)savedState;
    Text = state[0];
    Text1 = state[1];
}
```